# "The Devil and Simon Flagg" in Квант

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Did any of you ever read the translation into Russian of A. Porges' ["The Devil and Simon Flagg"](https://youtu.be/Ieu0H2DLJmo) which was featured in the magazine Квант once? If so, could you tell me the issue in which it appeared?

I know this question might not be suitable for MO but, since I am really interested in settling it, I dare to pose it here...

Let me thank you in advance for your attention and support.

Comment: No. I only remember reading it in English in an anthology.  Is there not an online index to search in Russian?  Gerhard "Surely There's One By Now?" Paseman, 2017.08.09.

Comment: At http://kvant.mccme.ru there is a Russian page which is an archive.  If you search for devil (the Russian word for it), you are likely to find it. Gerhard "Assumes You Can Type Cyrillic" Paseman, 2017.08.09.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in [issue 8, 1972, pp. 17-22](http://kvant.mccme.ru/1972/08/sajmon_flegg_i_dyavol.htm).

Comment: Yep, it seems like you've found it! Thanks a bunch for taking the time to track it down.